# Where do I programatically change textcolor onresume() or oncreate() in my Android app

Tags: android

In my Android app, I am using a header xml layout file that is included across many activities. The text on the header file is black in the xml layout file.

In one of my activity, I need the text to be blue for the header. As I am using the same header layout file across different activities, I am trying to set the textcolor programmatically for it.

Something like `tvNotification.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);`

My question is where should I use this statement oncreate() or onresume(). Based on the activity lifecyle, I think I should use it in onresume(), but just wanted to check. I have used something similar to this in oncreate() earlier and did not run into any issues. So, is it ok if I use it in oncreate() as well. Can there be any problem like the text being shown as black, if I use the above code in oncreate()

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the color will not change after the Activity is created, then `onCreate()` is just fine. If it can change based on user activity elsewhere, then do that in `onResume()` so you are always up to date once user returned to your app.

Comment: The textcolor remains the same in the given activity. So, I think its safe to use it in oncreate then. right?

Comment: then `onCreate()` is fine